# Is it possible to add a level completed badge using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap

I've a phonegap quiz app, that has lot of levels, each level has 10 questions. once the player answers 10 questions level will be completed. (he must answer 5 questions correctly in order to complete the level or else he failed the level and level is not completed yet)

Now what i need is, can i keep a "level completed" badge on each level player won/completed? a badge or just a text saying "completed" is fine. i want this to display on the chapter index page.

```js
/* questions and choices */

var quiztitle = "  chapter 1";
var quiz = [{
    "question": " 1. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 2. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 3. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 4. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 5. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 6. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 7. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 8. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 9. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
  {
    "question": " 10. question  ",
    "image": "",
    "choices": [
      " a. choice ",
      " b. choice ",
      " c. choice ",
      " d. choice "
    ],
    "correct": " b. choice ",
    "explanation": " answer explaination  ",
  },
]

/* score calcuations script */


var currentquestion = 0,
  score = 0,
  submt = true,
  picked;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  /**
   * HTML Encoding function for alt tags and attributes to prevent messy
   * data appearing inside tag attributes.
   */
  function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
  }

  /**
   * This will add the individual choices for each question to the ul#choice-block
   *
   * @param {choices} array The choices from each question
   */
  function addChoices(choices) {
    if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
      $('#choice-block').empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Resets all of the fields to prepare for next question
   */
  function nextQuestion() {
    submt = true;
    $('#explanation').empty();
    $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
    $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
    if (quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[currentquestion]['image'] != "") {
      if ($('#question-image').length == 0) {
        $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])).insertAfter('#question');
      } else {
        $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']));
      }
    } else {
      $('#question-image').remove();
    }
    addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
    setupButtons();
  }

  /**
   * After a selection is submitted, checks if its the right answer
   *
   * @param {choice} number The li zero-based index of the choice picked
   */
  function processQuestion(choice) {
    if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
      $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
        'background-color': '#50D943'
      });
      $('#explanation').html('<strong>Correct!</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
      score++;
    } else {
      $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
        'background-color': '#D92623'
      });
      $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
    }
    currentquestion++;
    $('#submitbutton').html('NEXT QUESTION &raquo;').on('click', function() {
      if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
        endQuiz();
      } else {
        $(this).text('Check Answer').css({
          'color': '#222'
        }).off('click');
        nextQuestion();
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * Sets up the event listeners for each button.
   */
  function setupButtons() {
    $('.choice').on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#e1e1e1'
      });
    });
    $('.choice').on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#fff'
      });
    })
    $('.choice').on('click', function() {
      picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
      $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
      $(this).css({
        'border-color': '#222',
        'font-weight': 700,
        'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
      });
      if (submt) {
        submt = false;
        $('#submitbutton').css({
          'color': '#000'
        }).on('click', function() {
          $('.choice').off('click');
          $(this).off('click');
          processQuestion(picked);
        });
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * Quiz ends, display a message.
   */

  function endQuiz() {

    $('#explanation').empty();
    $('#question').empty();
    $('#choice-block').empty();
    $('#submitbutton').remove();
    $('#question').text("You got " + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
    $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
      'text-align': 'center',
      'font-size': '4em'
    }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');

    if (score > 2 || score == 2) {
      nextlevelshow();
    } else {
      samelevel();
    }
  }

  function samelevel() {
    $('#samelevel').show()
  }

  function nextlevelshow() {
    $('#nextlevel').show()
  }
  /**
   * Runs the first time and creates all of the elements for the quiz
   */
  function init() {
    //add title
    if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
      $(document.createElement('h1')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
    } else {
      $(document.createElement('h1')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
    }

    //add pager and questions
    if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
      //add pager
      $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
      //add first question
      $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
      //add image if present
      if (quiz[0].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[0]['image'] != "") {
        $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[0]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[0]['question'])).appendTo('#frame');
      }
      $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

      //questions holder
      $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame');

      //add choices
      addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

      //add submit button
      $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('Check Answer').css({
        'font-weight': 700,
        'color': '#222',
        'padding': '30px 0'
      }).appendTo('#frame');

      setupButtons();
    }
  }
  init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active" id="chat-panel">
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <p> Book name </p>
    <span class="title light-text"> Please select a Chapter to play  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>01</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn1.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>02</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn2.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>03</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn3.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>04</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn4.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>05</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn5.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>06</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn6.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact swipeable">
    <div class="contact-user bg-red"><span>07</span></div>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link animsition-link" href="jn7.html">
      <p> Chapter </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i run the html code above, this index page will be displayed, i need a badge just after each chapter for completed levels

[image: when i run the html code, this index page will be displayed, i need a badge just after each chapter for completed levels]
I'm new to programming and stack overflow. I was not able to post code correctly so I used code snippet (sorry).

any help will be highly appreciated. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Although, I could not completely understood your question but if you simply want to change the level html to COMPLETED you can use jQuery `html()` function. or if you want to add a badge you can use `append()` or `after()` functions. For more detailed answer please try to explain where exactly you want the completed badge.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RajanBenipuri thanks for the comment.  I've edited and added an image sample. hope now it is clear.

Comment: Please add the relevant JS or Jquery code as well.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri sorry. that is all (script) i use for entire quiz app. I do not have any other js code

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment, so posting as answer.

You can just add any element dynamically  , for example `<label>Completed</label>`, or any other element  and style it. You can add this at the end of whichever `<div class="contact swipeable">` you want. You can do this from javascript whenever your level is complete. Or you can also add any class to the div and style it.

Comment: Thanks but it will be gone once the app is restarted?

Comment: It will not go until you remove it! It is just adding a DOM element based on your script condition/logic.